# Setting variable 'as type'

Tags: c#

Came across this snippet of code today:

```
EventFeed feed = null;
feed = service.Query(eventQuery) as EventFeed;
```

Why the `as EventFeed` at the end? The return type of that function is already an `EventFeed`, so I'm struggling to see the benefit of such a statement.

I found it difficult to search for this problem so I'm asking on here. What are the advantages to writing a line like this?

Comment: `Query` seems to return `object` instead of `EventFeed`, [`as`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt(v=vs.110).aspx) tries to cast it accordingly. Have a look at [Casting and Type Conversions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx).

Comment: If `service.Query(eventQuery)` can't be cast to the type `EventFeed`, it is set to `null`.

Comment: One could argue that the fact that `feed` is declared as an `EventFeed`, the `as EventFeed` cast is redundant because that's obviously what you want. But there are probably some disadvantages to that :P Aside from that, it would make the language less easy to read.

Comment: @sharpcloud Only if that `Query` is declared to return an `EventFeed`, otherwise it certainly can have value

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`feed` might be declared as `EventFeed` however the result of `service.Query(eventQuery)` may not be.

Using `as` stops an exception from being thrown and you end up with `null` instead if the result of the expression cannot be cast as `EventFeed`.

You can read more about `as` here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the DataType returned from the `Query` call. `as` in this case will attempt to cast the result to the `EventFeed` type, otherwise return `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Your query may be returning an `object`

```
service.Query(eventQuery)
```

so you are casting this object as your data type.

Comment: So its just another way of casting?

Comment: yes it is used for conversions between compatible reference types

Comment: @Teifi yes, if it can't cast though, rather than throwing an exception is will return a null

Answer (score 0):

If the *method signature* for `Query` specifies that it returns an `EventFeed` (as opposed to returning a base class but you KNOW it's an `EventFeed`). then the `as` is unnecessary.

Just because you declare `feed` as an `EventFeed` doesn't mean that the object you get back from `Query` is.  You may be trying to put a square peg in a round hole.

Comment: Sorry I phrased the question badly. I wasn't under that assumption ;) What I meant was that I already knew that the return type was an `EventFeed`

Answer (score 0):

According your edit, if service.Query already returns an 'EventFeed', recasting it as such does nothing. Looks like duplicate code.